# Completing graph edges "around the world" to GeoPlot an itinerary

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geographics

My central goal is to plot a complex international inter-city itinerary on a world map, which might include repetitions of a single segment (e.g., New York to London or London to New York).  The original difficulty stemmed from the fact that `GeoPath` plotted every such "equivalent" segment atop each other, obscuring the number of such passages and confusing the viewer.

@Jose's clever solution to [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183158/generating-different-geopaths-for-multiple-equivalent-segments) was to use the internal routines of `Graph` to, in essence, plot a `MultiGraph` of the route atop a map, where the edges for an equivalent segment would be automatically displaced.

This works well (at least for spatially localized itineraries), but reveals or introduces two new problems when plotting a world itinerary:

- The graph path doesn't "know" the shortest route between cities, and thus sometimes renders an incredibly long segment when the actual shorter segment went "on the other side of the world."
- The edge rendering isn't smart enough to complete an edge that is broken because it goes "on the other side of the world."

See the example map below.  Indeed, there are separate edges for the Cape Town to Beijing (as desired), but alas only the portion of the edge near Cape Town is shown--not the portion near Beijing.  Moreover, the code doesn't "know" that the proper (shortest) route from San Francisco to Hong Kong is across the Pacific Ocean.

Here is my modification of @Jose's code, where I've used `DirectedEdge` (to show direction of travel) and where I've colored the segments sequentially by `Hue` (to help the viewer understand the sequence of the route) and used `Partition` to speed the entry of cities on an itinerary:

```
ents = Partition[
      {Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
       Entity["City", {"HongKong", "HongKong", "HongKong"}], 
       Entity["City", {"Beijing", "Beijing", "China"}], 
       Entity["City", {"CapeTown", "WesternCape", "SouthAfrica"}], 
       Entity["City", {"Beijing", "Beijing", "China"}]}, 2, 1];

map = GeoGraphics[ents, 
         GeoProjection -> "Robinson", 
         GeoBackground -> "CountryBorders"];

proj = GeoProjection /. Options[map, GeoProjection];

uents = Union[Flatten[ents]];

coords = GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[uents], proj][[1]];

graph = Graph[uents,
   MapThread[
    Style, {(DirectedEdge @@@ ents), 
     Hue /@ (Range[Length[ents]]/Length[ents])}],
   VertexCoordinates -> coords,
   EdgeStyle -> Thick];

Show[map[[1]], graph, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: Map with missing portions of edges]

***Question***

In short, how can @Jose's code be modified to solve the two problems listed above:  1) produce "split edges" that go the shortest distance "around the world," and 2) show both portions of the edges?

Incidentally, I wouldn't mind using a different `GeoProjection` if it would solve these problems.  However, I've tried every such projection and none quite solve the full problem.  Perhaps, too, there is a way to embed a `Graph` on a sphere (the earth) and then convert that through a GeoProjection to a GeoMap.

Here is `Mercator` and a truncated range, which avoids breaking paths, but retains the problem of an incorrect path (from San Francisco to Hong Kong):

[image: Mercator projection]

I think this functionality will be of great use to the *Mathematica* community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing my ideas from your [linked post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183225/4346):

```
Options[multiGeoPath] = {"Directed" -> True, "Offset" -> 1000};

multiGeoPath[spec:{{_, _}..}, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{locs, gpos, spec2, seen, dirQ, offset, cnt, path},
    locs = Union @@ spec;
    gpos = GeoPosition /@ locs;
    spec2 = spec /. Dispatch[Thread[locs -> gpos]];

    Scan[(seen[#] = 0)&, Sort /@ spec2];
    dirQ = TrueQ[OptionValue["Directed"]];
    offset = OptionValue["Offset"];

    Table[
      cnt = (seen[Sort[s]] += 1);
      path = offsetGeoPath[s, (-1)^cnt * Quotient[cnt, 2] * offset];
      If[dirQ, 
        Arrow[path],
        path
      ],
      {s, spec2}
    ]
]

offsetGeoPath[spec_, offset_] :=
  Block[{pts, degs, len},
    pts = Reverse[GeoGraphics`GeoEvaluate[GeoPath[spec]][[1]], {2}];
    degs = Prepend[GeoDirection @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1] - Quantity[90, "Degrees"], Quantity[0, "Degrees"]];

    len = Length[pts];

    Line @ Table[
      GeoDestination[
        GeoPosition[pts[[i]]], 
        GeoDisplacement[{1000offset Sin[\[Pi] (i - 1)/(len - 1)], degs[[i]]}]
      ],
      {i, Length[pts]}
    ]
  ]
```

Your example:

```
ents = Partition[
  {Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"HongKong", "HongKong", "HongKong"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Beijing", "Beijing", "China"}], 
   Entity["City", {"CapeTown", "WesternCape", "SouthAfrica"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Beijing", "Beijing", "China"}]}, 2, 1];

GeoGraphics[{Thick, Arrowheads[Medium], 
  MapIndexed[{ColorData[112][First[#2]], #1} &, multiGeoPath[ents]]}, 
  GeoRange -> "World", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Here's the full circuit. We can see here that the offset choices are not optimal, but it's a start:

```
ents2 = Join[Most[ents], Reverse[Rest[Reverse[ents]], {2}]];

GeoGraphics[{Thick, Arrowheads[Medium], 
  MapIndexed[{ColorData[112][First[#2]], #1} &, multiGeoPath[ents2]]},
  GeoRange -> "World", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: My mistake (I failed to copy the `Options`).  So... this works *perfectly*.  Thanks so very very much for the careful coding.  A grateful *Accept*.